# Using Sklearn permutation_importance with Keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

i try to use the permutation_importance function from sklearn with my Keras MLP like the following.

```
model = keras.Sequential(
[
    layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
    layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
    layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
]
)
```

It's a binary classification task to classify if a credit defaults or not.

Problem is that i want to use roc_auc as scoring funtction but it says:

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets

In other cases I solved this by using this function:

```
y_pred =(model.predict(attributes_x_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

But I don't know how to change the scoringfunction here to an individual one

```
r = permutation_importance(model, attributes_x_test, attributes_y_test,
                           n_repeats=30, random_state=0,
                           scoring='roc_auc' )
```

So I want to use my own function instead of "roc_auc" where I can use the above y_pred